# How can I uninstall my current java and install sun java 1.6

Tags: installation, java, android, jdk

I installed jdk using the following command:     sudo apt-get install default-jdk     but it is the wrong version. I need Java SE 1.6 for building Android. When I try building Android, I get a message: Checking build tools versions...

---

You are attempting to build with the incorrect version
of java.

Your version is: java version "1.6.0_24".
The correct version is: Java SE 1.6.

Please follow the machine setup instructions at
    https://source.android.com/source/download.html

---

How can I uninstall Java version "1.6.0_24" and install Java SE 1.6? I have alien installed so I can install .rpm packages.

Answer (score 2):

1.) If you’ve already installed OpenJDK (Or in Ubuntu generally it is already installed). Remove it by running this command:

```
sudo apt-get purge openjdk*
```

2.) Then:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
```

Then update:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

3.) Select which version you want
To install Oracle Java 8:

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

To install Oracle Java 7:

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

To install the Java 6:

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java6-installer
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install the Java 6 JDK from Ubuntu's own repository by running the following line in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk
```

However, I'm running Eclipse, the Android SDK and I'm able to compile and run Android applications with OpenJDK 7 installed. It can be installed with:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

Comment: This is not "Sun's" or "Oracle's" Java 1.6.