# I tried to transplant the wireless_tools to Android4.0 system, but I have a problem with Java

Tags: java, software-installation, android

My Linux system is [Ubuntu Kylin](https://www.ubuntukylin.com/), a new [official flavor](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) of Ubuntu spreading mainly in China.

I have changed some files, such as `wireless.22.`h, `ifrename.c` and `iwlib.h`, in `wireless_tools.29/` which is located in `Android4.0` root directory.
Then I followed these steps:

```
$ cd ~/Android4.0
$ su
$[key](change to root)
root# source build/envsetup.sh
root# cd ~/Android4.0/wireless_tools.2.9/
root# mm
```

Then I got a message telling me that:

```
Your version is: java version "1.7.0_21".
The correct version is: Java SE 1.6.
```

Then I did as [How can I uninstall my current java and install sun java 1.6](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253039/how-can-i-uninstall-my-current-java-and-install-sun-java-1-6) After that, Java was installed successfully, but when I tried `mm` again:

```
Your version is: java version "1.6.0_27".
The correct version is: Java SE 1.6.
```

Then I tried [Establishing a Build Environment](https://source.android.com/source/initializing.html) (in the Android documentation), but it didn't work.

How can I install "java SE 1.6." correctly?

Comment: On an unrelated note, it's recommended that you use `sudo` for each command rather than staying in `root`.